# SharePoint web part storage with multiple instances of web part on same page

Tags: sharepoint, moss, web-parts

I have a custom web part I've built, that I'm attempting to place three instances of on a single page.  What I've noticed is that when I have a single instance on the page, the custom properties save and work appropriately.  When I then add two more instances of the same custom web part to the page, the following web parts do not save their custom property values.  I figure I must be doing something wrong when it comes to the WebPartStorage attribute.  Any thoughts?

```
[Browsable(true), Category("Miscellaneous"),
WebPartStorage(Storage.Personal), 
FriendlyName("List"), Description("List")]
public String List { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough, I ended up removing the default value and description attributes and my scenario began working.  Not a very helpful explanation, I know, but maybe it will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Storage.Shared rather than Storage.Personal?

This would help to isolate the personalisation store as the cause of the problem.

Additionally try removing the FriendlyName and Description attributes.